# Assigning a global hotkey to a functionality of an appilcation in KDE

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, audacity

How can I set global shortcut keys to `Pause` and `Record` buttons in `audacity`?

Options of `vlc` allow assigning global hotkeys but there's not such options in `audacity`.

Comment: Can you control audacity externally, e.g. via the command line?

Comment: I do not know how if possible.

Comment: I did have a quick search, but I'm not sure if it's possible to control it externally. If not, then I suspect it's not possible to assign global hotkeys either.

Comment: One possible way to do this is to use `xdotool` to inject a keystroke to a particular window. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87839/18887

Comment: thanks. But I could not get it work. There is also a key sending system in KDE. That system did not work too.

Comment: Ah yes, so there is. There is so much to KDE that I haven't scratched the surface of.