# Is it possible for command line to open a website and paste the clip board to a text box?

Tags: command-line, chrome, clipboard

I have some text in a file copied to the clipboard via command line and I then wish to paste this content to a website.

```
cat file | pbcopy 

/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://google.com/'
```

(1) How do I paste to say google (if it's even possible)?

(2) Is it possible to open a different website, tab x amount of times and then paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending keystrokes to a graphical application from a command-line program you can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool) (you may need to install it first). See the answer by Gilles to the question "[How to send keystrokes (F5) from terminal to a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-process)" on Unix & Linux.