# Can I make i3 not recognize some mod commands?

Tags: i3

I find it ergonomically impossible to use anything other than the Control key as a mod key in i3, however I run into the problem that well-ingrained commands as ctrl+c, ctrl+v does not work anymore.

Is it possible to make i3 not recognize specific commands, like those above, as i3-commands? While still being able to use Control+D as an i3 command. What lines  do I add to the config file?

Comment: I don't think you can get i3 to ignore specific commands, but perhaps you can map them in i3 so they send the key strokes to the focused application. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-gui-program

Answer (score 0):

Just go into the i3 conf (`~/.config/i3/config`)
and uncomment these two bindings (I am not sure if $mod+c is prebinded).

```
$mod+v
$mod+c
```

$mod+v is normally used to go into vertical mode. 
If you need to use the vertical mode, I suggest using $mod+y instead.