# Run a shell script within an already running shell script

Tags: shell-script, cluster, slurm

I have a small SLURM cluster, which I am using to run jobs. I run a script and while that script is running, I want to enter a specific key command "t + enter". I believe I should do it by submitting another job, but I need it to run within the first running script.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  When you say you "want to enter `t + enter`", where is that keypress *going*?  Is it an input that the (first) script is waiting for?

Comment: Hi Jiggly, So while that script is running, I want to be able to input from another screen (i.e. from master to slave) t + Return (because it provides a certain function). I tried to use echo, but what that does is print a char "t" on screen, and when I press enter it is not taken as an input.

Comment: Is the "slave", ie. the recipient of the keypress, an X window?  If so, you should consider `xdotool` as described in eg. [How to send keystrokes (F5) from a terminal to a GUI program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-gui-program)

Comment: Thank you, will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

George,

You would not want to queue a separate sbatch command to do this.  If you used the OpenHPC stack, you could potentially use `wwsh ssh -a <command>` where the `-a` is for all or alternatively replace this with the nodes that you want to run the command on.

As for doing it from your existing batch script, have you considered using `expect`?  The `expect` program would allow you to type something like `send -- "t\r"` (the t character followed by a return key) if the time that you needed the input to be run would be deterministic.  If you want more information on `expect`, check out something like https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/ .

In my experience can be helpful if your cluster doesn't have a lot of space or you want max performance to use a command line only approach instead of installing x11 on a system (or at least the parts of it required to run `xdotool`).  Personal comfort level will dictate this.